# How can i get my UITableViewController Instance when Segued?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a question. I have a class which is implementing the `DatasourceDelegate` for a `UITableView`.

My `TableViewController` is segued from a pop-over which i have set onto a `UIBarButton` in a toolbar. (this toolbar is part of a `UINavigationController`).

My problem now is that i dont how to pass my `datasource` object to my `UITableviewController`. so the question is. how can i get the instance of the `UITableviewController` that has been segued from the toolbar in my navigation controller?

Comment: Are you saying that the UIBarButton is the sourceViewController and the UITableViewController is the destinationViewController of the segue?

Comment: segue.destinationViewController doesnot work ? First get the segue and then the destination view controller in the segue should be the tableview controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the prepareForSeque method in the previous viewController you can access segue.destinationViewController. Then cast that into what you need `(UITableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController` so you can access custom methods to set the data object or set the data delegate

Something like

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      SomeClasViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
      [vc setDataObject:SomeDataObject];
}
```